# Dreamweaver Regedit Search and Replace

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, regedit

I currently have 1300 instances of HTML that I need to replace. The problem is that every 6 or so instances have a different url for the href tag located in the code blog.

In Dreamweaver, what is the proper regedit to search and replace all of this and disregard the different urls?

The code to search for follows the format below.  The text inside the paragraph tag and link tags is always going to be the same. Only the href url differs.

```
<p>Some text here <a href="https://mylink.com" target="_blank">Link text</a>.</p>
```

Comment: I think `<p>Some text here <a href="[^"]+" target="_blank">Link text</a>.</p>` would do it. Assuming your `href`s all close correctly, always use double quotes, and never have double quotes inside.

Comment: It depends on what you're going to replace it with. If there is nothing re-useable, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*<a href='?"?(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www.)?\w*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,3}'?"?\s?(target='?"?[_a-zA-Z]{0,8}'?"?)?\s*>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*<\/a>[.]?<\/p>
```

Tested working on the following strings:

```
<p>Some text here <a href="https://mylink.com" target="_blank">Link text</a>.</p>
<p>Some other text here <a href="mylink.ag" target="_blank">Link text</a>.</p>
<p>Some text here<a href='https://mylink.com' target='_blank'  >Link text</a>.</p>
<p>Some text here <a href='https://mylink2.com' target="_blank">Link text</a></p>
```

Cant cover every situation but this gives you a good chance of matching even if the strings aren't all perfectly formed.

Test at regex101